# How to login simultaneous user without loggin out the other user

Tags: php, session

Hi guys I am making a project for learning purposes. What I want is to login 2 or 3 accounts simultaneously into my website. Now the problem is when I login another account in a different tab in chrome browser. Somehow the other logged in account gets mixed with the other account. Is there anyway I can manage multiple login?

Comment: Use an array for your tokens?

Comment: This is the norm for session based web 'logins'.

Comment: is there any aritcle u can suggest for me to read or study? @Progrock

Comment: A good starting point is having a good grasp of how web sessions work, and how to do sessions in Php.  As you say you usually have a login tied to a browser instance, rather than an individual login per tab.  This may not be what you want, but it is what people are used to.  Here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368653/how-to-differ-sessions-in-browser-tabs

Comment: yes you can manage multiple logins if you are using different browsers or by using private browser windows

Comment: Using Session
You might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808498/php-session-per-tab)

Answer (score 0):

Use $_SESSION to keep track the logins: [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)