# Maintaining multiple session through multiple tabs in php

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies, session-state

I have a web application through which i can run tests.A user can run multiple tests simultaneously by opening the same application in separate tabs. The tests take longer time.So i want to maintain session for each run.Whenever a user returns back,I want show all his active sessions and open the sessions in each separate tab.How can we achieve this?Can we maintain multiple cookies for a user at a time?can we choose which cookies to be sent with a request?Please give insights on how to achieve this use case and small code snippet would help.

Thanks in advance.

The question, [PHP Multiple Concurrent Sessions Per User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067009/php-multiple-concurrent-sessions-per-user), didn't help me with how to achieve my usecase. The accepted answer is not clear. Thats the reason i posted new question.Please help me.

Comment: Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067009/php-multiple-concurrent-sessions-per-user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Multiple Concurrent Sessions Per User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067009/php-multiple-concurrent-sessions-per-user)

Comment: I want better way of doing it.The question does not answer on how to achieve my requirement.

Comment: The solution asks user to pass session name in the URL which I dont want to do.How can we achieve using multiple cookies is want i want to know?Thanks for responding.